# Expected Utility Method and a Repeated Game Solution

Tags: numerical-methods, game-theory, computational-mathematics, utility, algorithmic-game-theory

I am trying to replicate Bruce B. de Mesquita's (BDM) results on political game theory for prediction. Based on where actors stand on issues, their capabilities, salience, BDM's method attempts to find the eventual decision point by simulating a game. He reportedly used this method with much success; and published his results in successive journals, the latest of which is (1). This is his so-called "expected utility method", there is a newer method (3) but there is less documentation on that, so I wanted to use EU model first.

Scholz et.al tried to replicate the findings and documented his work here (2). I took his work as basis, since a lot of BDM articles / books are behind paywalls. There are also the gentleman here (4), they took Scholz's work as the basis, added a machine learning method on top, and created a new product.

I wrote the code, however I am not sure I was successful at replicating results. I would appreciate another pair of eyes to review the code to see if truly reflects the math shared in (2).

There was another attempt for coding Scholz's approach in Python, see (6). The author, Mr Velev, was even provided the Java code by Scholz for reference. The code always assumes Q=1, and runs fine on emission data. However on Iran data and EMU, the mean/median does not budge from the starting values.

Note: if anyone wants to duplicate my results but not too familiar with Python, the easiest installation is through Anaconda - http://continuum.io/downloads . Also FYI for first time users of this site - SE allows posters and commenters to use LaTeX math between `$`..`$` signs.

Here is scholz.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

Q = 1.0 ; T = 1.0

class Game:

    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df
        # dictionaries of df variables - used for speedy access
        self.df_capability = df.Capability.to_dict()    
        self.df_position = df.Position.to_dict()    
        self.df_salience = df.Salience.to_dict()    
        self.max_pos = df.Position.max()
        self.min_pos = df.Position.min()

    def weighted_median(self):
        self.df['w'] = self.df.Capability*self.df.Salience 
        self.df['w'] = self.df['w'] / self.df['w'].sum()
        self.df['w'] = self.df['w'].cumsum()
        return float(self.df[self.df['w']>=0.5].head(1).Position)

    def mean(self):
        return (self.df.Capability*self.df.Position*self.df.Salience).sum() / \
               (self.df.Capability*self.df.Salience).sum()

    def Usi_i(self,i,j,ri=1.):
        tmp1 = self.df_position[i]-self.df_position[j]
        tmp2 = self.max_pos-self.min_pos
        return 2. - 4.0 * ( (0.5-0.5*np.abs(float(tmp1)/tmp2) )**ri)

    def Ufi_i(self,i,j,ri=1.):
        tmp1 = self.df_position[i]-self.df_position[j]
        tmp2 = self.df.Position.max()-self.df.Position.min()
        return 2. - 4.0 * ( (0.5+0.5*np.abs(float(tmp1)/tmp2) )**ri )

    def Usq_i(self,i,ri=1.):
        return 2.-(4.*(0.5**ri))

    def Ui_ij(self,i,j):
        tmp1 = self.df_position[i] - self.df_position[j]
        tmp2 = self.max_pos-self.min_pos
        return 1. - 2.*np.abs(float(tmp1) / tmp2) 

    def v(self,i,j,k):
        return self.df_capability[i]*self.df_salience[i]*(self.Ui_ij(i,j)-self.Ui_ij(i,k)) 

    def Pi(self,i):
        l = np.array([[i,j,k] for (j,k) in itertools.combinations(range(len(self.df)), 2 ) if i!=j and i!=k])
        U_filter = np.array(map(lambda (i,j,k): self.Ui_ij(j,i)>self.Ui_ij(i,k), l))
        lpos = l[U_filter]
        tmp1 = np.sum(map(lambda (i,j,k): self.v(j,i,k), lpos))
        tmp2 = np.sum(map(lambda (i,j,k): np.abs(self.v(j,i,k)), l))
        return float(tmp1)/tmp2

    def Ubi_i(self,i,j,ri=1):
        tmp1 = np.abs(self.df_position[i] - self.weighted_median()) + \
               np.abs(self.df_position[i] - self.df_position[j])
        tmp2 = np.abs(self.max_pos-self.min_pos)
        return 2. - (4. * (0.5 - (0.25 * float(tmp1) / tmp2))**ri)

    def Uwi_i(self,i,j,ri=1):
        tmp1 = np.abs(self.df_position[i] - self.weighted_median()) + \
               np.abs(self.df_position[i] - self.df_position[j])
        tmp2 = np.abs(self.max_pos-self.min_pos)
        return 2. - (4. * (0.5 + (0.25 * float(tmp1) / tmp2))**ri)

    def EU_i(self,i,j,r=1):
        term1 = self.df_salience[j] * \
                ( self.Pi(i)*self.Usi_i(i,j,r) + ( 1.-self.Pi(i) )*self.Ufi_i(i,j,r) )
        term2 = (1-self.df_salience[j])*self.Usi_i(i,j,r)
        term3 = -Q*self.Usq_i(i,r)
        term4 = -(1.-Q)*( T*self.Ubi_i(i,j,r) + (1.-T)*self.Uwi_i(i,j,r) )
        return term1+term2+term3+term4

    def EU_j(self,i,j,r=1):
        return self.EU_i(j,i,r)

    def Ri(self,i):
        # get all j's expect i
        l = [x for x in range(len(self.df)) if x!= i]
        tmp = np.array(map(lambda x: self.EU_j(i,x), l))
        numterm1 = 2*np.sum(tmp)
        numterm2 = (len(self.df)-1)*np.max(tmp)
        numterm3 = (len(self.df)-1)*np.min(tmp)
        return float(numterm1-numterm2-numterm3) / (numterm2-numterm3)

    def ri(self,i):
        Ri_tmp = self.Ri(i)
        return (1-Ri_tmp/3.) / (1+Ri_tmp/3.)

    def do_round(self,df):
        self.df = df; df_new = self.df.copy()        
        # reinit
        self.df_capability = self.df.Capability.to_dict()    
        self.df_position = self.df.Position.to_dict()    
        self.df_salience = self.df.Salience.to_dict()    
        self.max_pos = self.df.Position.max()
        self.min_pos = self.df.Position.min()

        offers = [list() for i in range(len(self.df))]
        ris = [self.ri(i) for i in range(len(self.df))]
        for (i,j) in itertools.combinations(range(len(self.df)), 2 ):
            if i==j: continue
            eui = self.EU_i(i,j,r=ris[i])
            euj = self.EU_j(i,j,r=ris[j])
            if eui > 0 and euj > 0  and np.abs(eui) > np.abs(euj):
                # conflict - actor i has upper hand
                j_moves = self.df_position[i]-self.df_position[j]
                print i,j,eui,euj,'conflict', i, 'wins', j, 'moves',j_moves
                offers[j].append(j_moves)
            elif eui > 0 and euj > 0  and np.abs(eui) < np.abs(euj):
                # conflict - actor j has upper hand
                i_moves = self.df_position[j]-self.df_position[i]
                print i,j,eui,euj,'conflict', j, 'wins', i, 'moves',i_moves
                offers[i].append(i_moves)
            elif eui > 0 and euj < 0 and np.abs(eui) > np.abs(euj):
                # compromise - actor i has the upper hand
                print i,j,eui,euj,'compromise', i, 'upper hand'
                xhat = (self.df_position[i]-self.df_position[j]) * np.abs(euj/eui)
                offers[j].append(xhat)
            elif eui < 0 and euj > 0 and np.abs(eui) < np.abs(euj):
                # compromise - actor j has the upper hand
                print i,j,eui,euj,'compromise', j, 'upper hand'
                xhat = (self.df_position[j]-self.df_position[i]) * np.abs(eui/euj)
                offers[i].append(xhat)
            elif eui > 0 and euj < 0 and np.abs(eui) < np.abs(euj):
                # capitulation - actor i has upper hand
                j_moves = self.df_position[i]-self.df_position[j]
                print i,j,eui,euj,'capitulate', i, 'wins', j, 'moves',j_moves
                offers[j].append(j_moves)
            elif eui < 0 and euj > 0 and np.abs(eui) > np.abs(euj):
                # capitulation - actor j has upper hand
                i_moves = self.df_position[j]-self.df_position[i]
                print i,j,eui,euj,'capitulate', j, 'wins', i, 'moves',i_moves
                offers[i].append(i_moves)
            else:
                print i,j,eui,euj,'nothing'

        # choose offer requiring minimum movement, then
        # update positions
        print offers
        df_new['offer'] = map(lambda x: 0 if len(x)==0 else x[np.argmin(np.abs(x))],offers)
        df_new.loc[:,'Position'] = df_new.Position + df_new.offer

        # in case max/min is exceeded
        df_new.loc[df_new['Position']>self.max_pos,'Position'] = self.max_pos
        df_new.loc[df_new['Position']<self.min_pos,'Position'] = self.min_pos
        return df_new
```

I ran this code on EU emission agreement, Iran presidential election data from (4), on the British EMU data from (5) (for Labor party case), and two small synthetic datasets I created.

> ```
> Actor,Capability,Position,Salience
> Netherlands,8,40,80
> Belgium,8,70,40
> Luxembourg,3,40,20
> Germany,16,40,80
> France,16,100,60
> Italy,16,100,60
> UK,16,100,90
> Ireland,5,70,10
> Denmark,5,40,100
> Greece,8,70,70
>
> Actor,Capability,Position,Salience
> Jalili,24,10,70
> Haddad,8,20,100
> Gharazi,1,40,100
> Rezayi,20,40,60
> Ghalibaf,64,50,100
> Velayati,7,50,25
> Ruhani,21,80,100
> Aref,30,100,70
>
> Actor,Capability,Position,Salience
> Labor Pro EMU,100,75,40
> Labor Eurosceptic,50,35,40
> The Bank of England,10,50,60
> Technocrats,10,95,40
> British Industry,10,50,40
> Institute of Directors,10,40,40
> Financial Investors,10,85,60
> Conservative Eurosceptics,30,5,95
> Conservative Europhiles,30,60,50
>
> Actor,Capability,Position,Salience
> A,100,100,100
> B,100,90,100
> C,50,50,50
> D,5,5,10
> E,10,10,20
>
> Actor,Capability,Position,Salience
> A,100,5,100
> B,100,10,100
> C,50,50,50
> D,5,100,10
> E,10,90,20
> ```

The emission prediction is good, near 8. For Iran the simulation does not converge, mean ends up around 45 which is far cry from Preana's and BDMs findings which is around 80. For EMU data, authors report anti-euro finding near 4, my finding is around 44, at least it is less than 50, but not as low as 4 either.

The synthetic dataset is fine, always coalescing near top and bottom, but this is a simple case. I am attaching the graph outputs below as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any feedback would be appreciated,

---

1. Bueno De Mesquita BB (1994) Political forecasting: an expected utility method. In: Stockman F (ed.) European Community Decision Making. Yale, CT: Yale University Press, Chapter 4,
   71–104.
2. https://oficiodesociologo.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/scholz-et-all-unravelling-bueno-de-mesquita-s-group-decision-model.pdf
3. A New Model for Predicting Policy Choices: Preliminary Tests http://irworkshop.sites.yale.edu/sites/default/files/BdM_A%20New%20Model%20for%20Predicting%20Policy%20ChoicesREvised.pdf
4. http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?paperID=49058
5. The Predictability of Foreign Policies, The British EMU Policy, https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/3198774/13854.pdf
6. J. Velev, Python Code, https://github.com/jmckib/bdm-scholz-expected-utility-model.git
7. The Visible Hand, http://s3.amazonaws.com/os_extranet_files_test/27236_59690_fa12visible.pdf

Comment: Skimming through your reference 2, I see a lot of remarks to the effect that the model has changed over time and that there are controversies how to treat certain terms. Given the complexity of the whole undertaking, it seems hopeless to pinpoint the reasons for discrepancies unless you know precisely which model you're trying to replicate. Reference 5 doesn't seem to specify the dynamics, only the expected utilities. This is the most glaring discrepancy, quantitatively but also qualitatively in that their Tories never budge. I'd concentrate on finding out how the dynamics is defined there.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried to stick to (2) as much as possible. Some confusion I still have is $P_i$ in pg. 521 has a "k if arg >0" statement. I took that to mean "use only that $c_k s_k (|x_k-x_j|-|x_k-x_i|)$ terms that are $>0$ for the specific $k$".  Also $E_{ij}^i$ definition in pg. 520 has an $s_j$ in it, but so does  $E_{ji}^j$, IMO that should've been $s_i$. From the viewpoint $j$ "challenges" $i$ and $i$ "resists" (2) usage makes no sense.

Comment: In both cases I think you're right, but I'm not sure. On p. $520$ it's not clear to me why they even write the equation out twice, since except for the $s_j$ the two versions follow from each other simply by swapping $i$ and $j$. This seems to be the only place where this peculiar redundancy occurs; further up they're always only talking about $E^i(U_{ij})$. That makes me wonder whether it might be the left-hand sides that contain a typo, not (or not only) $s_j$.

Comment: Right! It could be LHS.. It's interesting, in (3) pg. 7 BDM talks about $E^A(U_{AB}),E^A(U_{BA}),E^B(U_{AB}), E^B(U_{BA})$, but (2) only gives one E definition, the second was typo'd, this might mean 2 or 3 others are missing.

Comment: Only two of these four need to be defined; the other two follow by swapping $A$ and $B$. I think BDM only mentions all four to explain how they relate to the perspectives of $A$ and $B$; he doesn't define them separately.

Comment: I won't be looking into this any further; there's too much stuff with too many uncertainties -- I'm not sure whether you have enough information in those papers to debug this. Have you considered contacting the authors to get more precise algorithms or to clear up ambiguities?

Comment: Ok thanks for these comments anyway. And yes, I contacted all authors of papers above, including BDM. Hopefully I get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from Dr. Mesquita, I am sharing it below:

> I have had a quick look at the code -- I don't have time right now to
>   look really carefully -- and it appears that what you are computing
>   you are computing correctly, but you do not have some critical
>   elements of that old model. You do not have a mechanism for working
>   out when the "game" ends. The model includes a set of discounting
>   conditions for identifying when the player interactions are expected
>   to end. Unfortunately, that element is proprietary and I am not the
>   owner of the software anymore and so am restricted from discussing how
>   that works. Also the model handles salience a bit differently than you
>   have done and this too is proprietary and not owned by me.
>
> If I may offer some advice -- develop, as you are doing, a body of
>   data with known outcomes and then experiment with sensible ways to
>   calculate when only partially myopic players would end the game -- the
>   weighted median at that round of play will be the predicted outcome.
>   See if you can succeed in getting your assumptions about game ending
>   to converge on the known correct results and you will have a
>   reasonable replication.
>
> Frankly I do not understand the desire to replicate that old model. It
>   is only quasi-game theoretic (really it is more of a rational
>   expectations decision theoretic model) and, unlike my current model,
>   it is non-Bayesian so player learning is inefficient.

Some takeaways from this is something I was suspecting all along, the "old model" is not entirely game theoretic (the new one solves for the Perfect Bayesian Equilibrium -communicated to me in a seperate conversation-), and there are some parts of the method that are not known; One can labor to figure these out, but I need to move on to other tasks. If anyone can go ahead with this knowledge, please do so (and inform your findings here).